# is a Horcrux single-use or can it be used multiple times?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

can one get resurrected with a single Horcrux multiple times, or can the Horcrux only be used once?

for example, back when Voldemort was alive and had 7x Horcruxes, would killing Voldemort's body be about as good as taking out 1 of the Horcruxes?

Comment: "*A Horcrux is the word used for an object in which a person has concealed part of their soul... Well, you split your soul, you see, and hide part of it in an object outside the body. Then, even if one's body is attacked or destroyed, one cannot die, for part of the soul remains earthbound and undamaged."*

Comment: You don't use up horcruxes like extra lives